# clear filtering using dropdown list primefaces datatable

Tags: java, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.0 and Weblogic application server and JSF2.0.

Question : how to Clear dropdown Filtering in p:datatable .

My Code : XHTml :

```
<p:column rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; width:80px;"
    filterBy="#{monitorLookUpdata.status}" 
    sortBy="#{monitorLookUpdata.status}"
    filterMatchMode="contains" filterMaxLength="9" id="statusId"
    filterStyle="width:80%;">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="Status" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="filter">
        <h:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('monitorLookUp').filter()" class="ui-simple-text">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Open" itemValue="Open" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Delivered" itemValue="Delivered" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Closed" itemValue="Closed" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

Java Code :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("filteredData");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p:column rowspan="3" style="text-align: center; width:80px;"
                                            filterBy="#{monitorLookUpdata.status}" 
                                            filterOptions="#{monitorLookupHandler.options}"
                                            sortBy="#{monitorLookUpdata.status}"
                                            filterMatchMode="contains" filterMaxLength="9" id="statusId"
                                            filterStyle="width:80%;">
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                            <br/><br/>
                                                <h:outputText value="Status" />
                                </f:facet>


                                        </p:column>
```

And Java Code will be  :

```
private SelectItem[] options;
options = new SelectItem[4]; 
        options[0] = new SelectItem(" ", " ");
        options[1] = new SelectItem("Open", "Open");
        options[2] = new SelectItem("Delivered", "Delivered");
        options[3] = new SelectItem("Closed", "Closed");
```

Now above code working as expected . Thanks All .